# Map network drive automatically via ps1 - not working

Tags: bash, powershell

I have a network drive (Z:, dedicated server) from which I am running all my development applications. Every now and then Windows 10 loses the ability to access the drive, in which case I typically type in `net use Z: //xx.x.x.xx/abc`. This works fine, but since it happens periodically I was looking to automate this process via a powershell script. This is what I came up with (newbie to powershell):

```
If ( !(Test-Path Z:) ) {
    Test-Path -Path "\\xx.x.x.xx\abc" -PathType Container
    net use Z: \\xx.x.x.xx\abc
} Else {
    Write-Host "**********`n*`n* Drive already mapped`n*`n**********`n"

    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
}
```

The problem is that executing this file does not properly map the drive on my computer. Z is still unavailable, and only typing this out manually resolves the problem. This is the power shell error I get when trying to access the Z drive without proper mapping:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Z:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Do I have to run the shell with privileges? How can I properly automate this?

Comment: `net use Z: \\xx.x.x.xx\abc /persistent:yes`

Comment: @Theo the drive still didn't persist unfortunately